# TypeError: validar_usuario() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'

Tags: mysql, python, angular, flask, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación con Angular y Python, tengo una función llamada **validar_usuario** para que una vez autenticado el usuario esta función obtenga los permisos de dicho usuario de la base de datos y Angular muestre el contenido de la aplicación según el tipo de permiso.

El problema radica en que Python me envía el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: validar_usuario() missing 1 required positional argument: 'email'
```

Y no sé qué está pasando.

Mi código es:

```
@app.route('/validarUsuario', methods = ["POST"])
def validar_usuario(email):
    conection = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root','root', 'users')
    dato = (email)
    cursor = conection.cursor() 
    sql_query = "SELECT permiso_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql_query, dato)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print (data)
    return jsonify(data)
```

Utilizando Postman, le envío el siguiente parámetro:

```
    {
    "email": "erick.frias@typeit.com.mx"
    }
```

Comment: Ese parámetro se lo envías en JSON, en el *body* de la solicitud, ¿ cierto ?

Comment: @Trauma asi es.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tomado de aquí: [How to get POSTed json in Flask ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20001229/8663418)

Para obtener parámetros enviados en el *body* de la solicitud, tienes que usar la propiedad `request.json`, disponible tras importar el módulo:

```
import request

...

@app.route('/validarUsuario', methods = ["POST"])
def validar_usuario( ):
    email = request.json['email']

    conection = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root','root', 'users')
    dato = (email)
    cursor = conection.cursor() 
    sql_query = "SELECT permiso_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql_query, dato)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    print (data)
    return jsonify(data)
```

Observa que esta función de ruta **no requiere ningún argumento**. Argumentos a la función son extraidos por flask de la URL, y tu no estás usando ninguno, sino que lo extraes del propio *body* de la solicitud.

Comment: Perfecto, funciono. Muchas gracias